# Need with interpreting statistical equations into R to run an ANOVA-type test

Tags: r

I am trying to interpret the statistical equation in this paper such that I will be able to generate R code and run a script for the ANOVA-type test in the paper (doi:10.1016/j.csda.2008.04.006) (apologies in advance if you can't access it!!!)

Essentially, I am confused on how they are formulating their 'R' matrix and their 'R bar' matrix.. I see that it says it is a "matrix where a variable corresponds to a row, and multivariate observation corresponds to a column"

[image]

My dataset is

```
Cattle <- read.table(text=" Treatment Replicate Weight_Loss Persistent Head_Size Salebarn_Q
                             'LA 200'         1       17.90      14.10     14.25        1.0
                             'LA 200'         2       19.30      15.30      2.56        1.0
                             'LA 200'         3       19.50      16.82      5.80        1.5
                             'LA 200'         4       18.94      12.70      7.51        1.5
                               Excede         1       19.60      11.20     14.52        1.0
                               Excede         2       19.50      10.54      9.83        1.0
                               Excede         3       19.10      10.83      3.82        0.5
                               Excede         4       20.40      11.00      0.04        1.0
                              Micotil         1       17.30      14.29      1.62        1.0
                              Micotil         2       20.00      11.65      0.13        3.0
                              Micotil         3       18.10      10.89      2.41        0.0
                              Micotil         4       19.50      12.43      5.93        2.0
                               Zoetis         1       18.50      25.48     10.08        1.0
                               Zoetis         2       17.60      20.12     11.93        1.0
                               Zoetis         3       19.70      23.29      7.93        2.5
                               Zoetis         4       18.50      28.32     13.08        3.0", header=TRUE)
```

and so far I have this code for what I believe they could potentially be talking about

```
R<-matrix(c(17.9,   14.1,   14.25,  1,
+           19.3,   15.3,   2.56,   1,
+           19.5,   16.82,  5.8,    1.5,
+           18.94,  12.7,   7.51,   1.5,
+           19.6,   11.2,   14.52,  1,
+           19.5,   10.54,  9.83,   1,
+           19.1,   10.83,  3.82,   0.5,
+           20.4,   11, 0.04,   1,
+           17.3,   14.29,  1.62,   1,
+           20, 11.65,  0.13,   3,
+           18.1,   10.89,  2.41,   0,
+           19.5,   12.43,  5.93,   2,
+           18.5,   25.48,  10.08,  1,
+           17.6,   20.12,  11.93,  1,
+           19.7,   23.29,  7.93,   2.5,
+           18.5,   28.32,  13.08,  3),nrow=16,ncol=4)

R_Bar<-matrix(c(18.91,19.65,18.73,18.58,14.73,10.89,12.32,24.30,7.53,7.05,2.52,10.76,1.25,0.875,1.50,1.88),nrow=4,ncol=4)
```

But I am not entirely sure.. also I have started the code for the rest of the paper something like

```
H<-matrix(0,p,p)
G<-matrix(0,p,p)
trH<-sum(diag(H))
trG<-sum(diag(G))
H<-for(i in 1:a){(1/(a-1))*sum(n*(Ri.-R..)*t(Ri.-R..))}
```

But again I'm generally just trying to decipher what they want to generate for R and thus Ri and R.. to put into the equation and generate G and H and so on..

Any help is very genuinely appreciated.

Comment: It looks like R is supposed to be a matrix of ranks, not the original values. So you would want to calculate `rank()` on each of your columns to generate R. A "matrix where a variable corresponds to a row, and multivariate observation corresponds to a column" implies that the matrix should be transposed relative to your original table (where a row is an observation, and a column is a variable).

Comment: Does this scraping from a title of a pdf from the JSS help? `Journal of Statistical Software
January 2017, Volume 76, Issue 4. doi: 10.18637/jss.v076.i04
Nonparametric Inference for Multivariate Data:
The R Package npmv`,  first author 
Amanda R. Ellis

Comment: My close vote was due to the lack of statistical specificity which I thought might be best clarified on CrossValidated.com. After said clarification, an enhanced version of this question specific to R packages might be on-topic.

Comment: @marius I think you are exactly right. as for the npmv package we are not allowed to use that.  I am going to try to make the ranked matrix and see if I can get something to work with, though I'm not entirely sure how to go about ranking my current matrix and generating a new one / what the dimensions should be..

Comment: @Marius would you use something like matrix(rank(Cattle,ties.method = "average"),p,p)  to generate the matrix you want? then use t( ) to transpose it?